# Why is the duration of an audio file recorded with record(forDuration: TimeInterval) slightly different than specified duration?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Thanks in advance for any help understanding this better.

The following is code which records audio for 3 seconds, and then plays back the audio and prints out the duration of the recorded audio. What I'm noticing is that the duration printed is 3.072 seconds. Not a clean 3.0 seconds. Why is this the case?

```swift
func record() {
    let audioFilename = FileManager.default.urls(
        for: .documentDirectory,
           in: .userDomainMask
    )[0].appendingPathComponent("\(UUID().uuidString).m4a")
    
    let audioRecorder = try? AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: [
        AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
    ])
    
    audioRecorder?.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder?.delegate = self
    
    audioRecorder?.record(forDuration: duration)
    
}

func play(url: URL) {
    preparePlayer(url: url)
    audioPlayer?.play()
    
    let audioAsset = AVURLAsset.init(url: url, options: [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true])
    
    audioAsset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration"]) {
        var error: NSError?
        let status = audioAsset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &error)
        
        switch status {
        case .loaded:
            let duration = audioAsset.duration
            let durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            print("Duration of played audio file -- \(durationInSeconds)s")
            break
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the 3 seconds, the scheduler probably can't schedule the code that stops recording immediately - there are lots of other things going on in your computer, after all. The microphone probably also needs to be turned off, and talking to hardware _takes time_. But seriously, do you really care about those 0.072 seconds?

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper - makes sense. So I guess if I wanted more precision I'd need a step to trim the audio

Comment: Could also be due to AAC frame packet size, which depending on your duration will give you either two or three extra packets (3 extra packets at 44100 is almost the duration you're seeing). m4a supports metadata that lets you specify the true duration, but either `AVAudioRecorder` isn't setting it or `AVURLAsset` isn't considering it.